# Code isn't displaying data from json page

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am trying to display the data from a json page to my page but the data is just showing up at `[object Object], [object Object], [object Object]`.

From what I guess, I have the data grabbed which is those objects in those arrays but I didn't write the code correctly to display the content?  I tried both JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse(), still no success.

Here is the link to the json: https://data.nasa.gov/resource/2vr3-k9wn.json

Here is the code:
edit: Now my code here isn't working at all. Gah

```
function Comet() {
    url = 'https://data.nasa.gov/resource/2vr3-k9wn.json'
    var cometRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    cometRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (cometRequest.readyState === 4 && cometRequest.status === 200) {
            var response = cometRequest.responseText,
                parsedComet = JSON.parse(response);
            for (line in parsedComet) {
                //console.log(line);
                for (i=0; i<line.length; i++) {
                    console.log(parsedComet[line][i]);
                } 
            }
    };
    }
    cometRequest.open("GET", url, true);
    cometRequest.send(null);
}
```

Comment: post your json structure.

Comment: https://data.nasa.gov/resource/2vr3-k9wn.json

Comment: Now this code isn't displaying data at all. I think I pasted the code that is worse. I am struggling

Comment: There is `line.length` in for loop should be `parsedComet[line].length`

Comment: Yes i've commented before checking your json. see answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure which data exactly are you trying to fetch, but you already have the `parsedComet[line]`, you don't need to add the `i` there.

Each `parsedComet[line]` is an Object (like this one):

```
{  
   "designation":"419880 (2011 AH37)",
   "discovery_date":"2011-01-07T00:00:00.000",
   "h_mag":"19.7",
   "i_deg":"9.65",
   "moid_au":"0.035",
   "orbit_class":"Apollo",
   "period_yr":"4.06",
   "pha":"Y",
   "q_au_1":"0.84",
   "q_au_2":"4.26"
}
```

So if you want to get the value of `orbit_class` for example you can use:

```
console.log(parsedComet[line]['orbit_class']);
```

```js
function Comet() {
    url = 'https://data.nasa.gov/resource/2vr3-k9wn.json'
    var cometRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    cometRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (cometRequest.readyState === 4 && cometRequest.status === 200) {
          debugger;
            var response = cometRequest.responseText,
                parsedComet = JSON.parse(response);
            for (line in parsedComet) {
              //console.log(line);
              console.log(parsedComet[line]);
            }
    };
    }
    cometRequest.open("GET", url, true);
    cometRequest.send(null);
}
Comet();
```

Comment: Need a closing quote after orbit_class

Answer (score 1):

You need to exchange internal for loop with external. the first one to loop over array objects and the other to loop over objects key & value.

```
function Comet() {
    url = 'https://data.nasa.gov/resource/2vr3-k9wn.json'
    var cometRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    cometRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (cometRequest.readyState === 4 && cometRequest.status === 200) {
            var response = cometRequest.responseText,
                parsedComet = JSON.parse(response);
            for (i=0; i<parsedComet.length; i++) {
            for (line in parsedComet[i]) {
                    console.log(parsedComet[i][line]);
                    //419880 (2011 AH37)
                    //2011-01-07T00:00:00.000
                    //etc....
                } 
            }
    };
    }
    cometRequest.open("GET", url, true);
    cometRequest.send(null);
}
```